# Re-rendering after sending a delete request in react not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I have React.js in the front-end and Express.js in the back-end. At the moment I am trying to delete a post from React with a Delete request and it works but I have to go to the url and hit enter before it shows the new list after deleting. I would like the page to re-render without having to hit refresh.

```
class Rentals extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            completelist: [],
            apiLoaded: false,
        }
        this.conditionalRentList = this.conditionalRentList.bind(this);
        this.handleDeleteButton = this.handleDeleteButton.bind(this);
        this.fetchAllRentals = this.fetchAllRentals.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchAllRentals();
    }

    fetchAllRentals() {
        fetch('api/listofrentals')
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((fullrental) => {
                this.setState((prevState) => {
                    return {
                        completelist: fullrental.rentalsData,
                        apiLoaded: true
                    }
                })
            })
    }

    conditionalRentList() {
        if (this.state.apiLoaded === true) {
            return (
                <RentalsComp
                    completelist={this.state.completelist}
                    handleDeleteButton={this.handleDeleteButton}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return <p> Loading </p>
        }
    }

    handleDeleteButton(idToBeDeleted) {
        fetch(`api/listofrentals/${idToBeDeleted}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.json === 200) {
                this.fetchAllRentals();
            }
        })
    }

}
```

the function `handleDeleteButton` should fetch all the listings and render it without having to refresh since it calls the `fetchAllRentals` function but its not working for some reason.

Comment: I'm wondering if your `this.setState` is actually working because the value of `this` my not be what you expect. Try setting this to a variable at the top of your function. eg `fetchAllRentals() { var that = this`    then you can use `that.setState` ...

Comment: Can you check what your `resp.json` is when you call the DELETE api?

Comment: hello, found out what was wrong, wanted to do `resp.status === 200` to see if it would go through and then fetch. I was doing resp.json for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was supposed to be resp.status===200 but was doing resp.json===200 instead.